# converting normal query into fancy or partition/over query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My query:

```
with cte as (
        select client_id,COUNT(patient_id) PatientCount from
        (
            select client_id,patient_id
            from F_ACCESSION_DAILY
            group by CLIENT_ID,PATIENT_ID
            having COUNT(ACCESSION_ID)=2
        ) a
        group by CLIENT_ID
)
```

works, but is not so useful to me. because although i can JOIN easily on this query, I will actually need to repeat this `WITH` statement many times because i need to be able to differentiate between:

```
having count(Accession_id)=2
```

and

```
having count(Accession_id)=3
```

and

```
having count(accession_id)=4
```

and so on until around 100

i was thinking to do something more like this:

```
select distinct client_id, patient_id, count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id,accession_id) patientcount
    from f_accession_daily
```

but i am stuck!

i was wondering if you can point me into the right direction on how to convert the initial query into something **more useable when having count(Accession)=many different values**?

thanks so much for your guidance.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and what is the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...?

```
   select client_id,accessioncount,COUNT(patient_id) PatientCount from 
    ( 
        select client_id,patient_id, count(accession_id) as accessioncount
        from F_ACCESSION_DAILY 
        group by CLIENT_ID,PATIENT_ID 
    ) a 
    group by CLIENT_ID,accessioncount
```